# Set different colors in SelectList

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, selectlist

I would like different options in my SelectList to have different colors (red/green) depending if they are active or not.

At the moment I do the following in the Controller:

```
ViewData["fooID"] = new SelectList(_context.foo, "fooID", "fooName", foo.fooID);
```

And the following on my View:

```
<select asp-for="fooID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.fooID"></select>
```

I would like to use something like:

```
class="@(foo.fooActive ? "green" : "red")"
```

But I guess I must use a different approach than ViewData?

Comment: why dont you just iterate over the items and create the option tags your self?

Comment: Your question is not complete: do you want to change the color dynamically (i.e. when the user selects them) or do you want to show which options were previously selected. I'm asking because Razor pages/views etc are NOT interactive. You render them once in response to a request, so any color that is selected during generation is permanent. If you want a dynamic page, either use Blazor or Javascript (or a JS framework), or prepare to do a whole page reload for every user interaction.

Comment: I was hoping there was a more dynamic way than iterating but I guess there isn't.
The colors should be set already when populating the SelectList and won't change. They are just reflecting which items are OK to select and which items are not active anymore.

Comment: The [`SelectListItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem) has the Property `Disabled`. Is that what you mean with "Active"? Or do you mean `Enabled`? You could use CSS to set the color of disabled or selected selectlist items.